# Error handling of Async Component in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I am using [Advanced Async Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Advanced-Async-Components) in vue js in the route file.

So when you navigate across the routes, the component will be fetched dynamically, and till the time it is being fetched the loader component will be displayed. If the component couldnt be downloaded becuase of network latency (exceeds timeout) or any other reasons, the error component will be rendered.

This all is working fine. The syntax is:

```
function lazyLoadView(AsyncView: any) {
  const AsyncHandler = () => ({
    component: AsyncView,
    loading: ComponentLoading,
    delay: 0,
    error: ComponentError,
    timeout: 6000,
  });

  return Promise.resolve({
    functional: true,
    render(h: any, { data, children }: any) {
      return h(AsyncHandler, data, children);
    },
  });
}

export const routes = [{
    path: '/abc',
    component: () => lazyLoadView(import('@routes/Abc/index.vue')),
  },{
    path: '/def',
    component: () => lazyLoadView(import('@routes/def/index.vue')),
  },
]
```

**My questions are:**

1. When the timeout exceeds, the error component is rendered. But the network call to the particular chunk is never aborted.
2. On navigating to route say `/abc` if the component `(ABC)` didnt render and so the error component did, then coming back to this route /abc after goin to some other route, what I see is the error component instantly mounted. How can I refetch the chunk to retry the fetching of component `ABC`?

Comment: I have some comments that not related to your question. Your code did not load the components on demand due to it will execute `import` immediately when the file is imported. **EDITED** Sorry my bad, just saw it is wrapped inside a closure.